# open modal window with paramters in mvc 4 using jqueryui

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to load a modal window with data dynamically based on a parameter sent by the host page. The host page will have a set of edit links in a table. Clicking on any of the edit links should open a window with corresponding data based on the row id sent in. The code I have below doesnt work. What changes will I need to make so that when I click on the Edit link I can send a rowid to the 'dialogMsg' div layer so that data can be dynamically placed in it

```
<div id="dialogMsg" title="Editing " + StudentFirstName >
            Show other student details here
</div>

<table >
<tr>
    <td>
        James
    </td> <td><a href="#" id="editlink">Edit</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        John
    </td> <td><a href="#" id="editlink">Edit</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Doe
    </td> <td><a href="#" id="editlink">Edit</a></td>
</tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () 
    {
        $("#dialogMsg").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Create an account": function () {
                    var bValid = true;

                    $(this).dialog("close");

                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }

        });


        $('#editlink')
        .click(function () {
            $('#dialogMsg').dialog('open');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You could populate the dialog message from a partial view on editing the link using ajax and then diplay it.

Comment: Take a look at his question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959639/return-partialview-from-jsonresult-actionmethod-back-to-ajax-post-and-display-th/15960456#15960456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes to your code:

```
<div id="dialogMsg" title="Editing ">Show other student details here</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>James</td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="editlink">Edit</a>
            <input type="javascript" class="personId" value="1" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="editlink">Edit</a>
            <input type="javascript" class="personId" value="2" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="editlink">Edit</a>
            <input type="javascript" class="personId" value="2" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dialogMsg").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Create an account": function () {
                    var bValid = true;

                    $(this).dialog("close");

                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }

        });


        $('.editlink').click(function () {
            $('#dialogMsg')
                .dialog('option', 'title', "Editing " 
                    + $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text())
                .dialog('open');

            var personId = $(this).closest('tr').find('.personId').val();
            // work it out with the ID here
        });
    });
</script>
```

Changes done:

1. Moved the title to the JavaScript. You cannot set the title attribute like this `<div id="dialogMsg" title="Editing " + StudentFirstName >`.
2. Changed the `id` attribute of the `Edit` link to `class` attribute. `id` must be unique for each element in the page.
3. Setting the dialog title in the JavaScript. `$(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text()).dialog('open');`. Here I am getting the nearest parent `tr` tag and get the text of the first `td` child tag.

**Edit:**

Added hidden field for ID with a css class. The class can be used in jQuery select for getting the ID.

Comment: Thanks. Now that the header is displayed. How do I pass the row ID of that record? The row ID will not be displayed on the grid. But I still need to send the id to the modal window to pull the record details from the database and display it in the modal window.

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr')` returns the selected row in the table. You can have a hidden field in each row for the ID. Then you can get the ID using `$(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=hidden]').val()`. You can save it in a variable and use it when the user clicks the button.

Comment: thanks, edit your answer and I will mark it as correct.. btw what if there are multiple input types on that row?

Comment: For multiple input types you can add a css class for the hidden field and select using the class. Look at the updated code for an understanding.