# close modal form on ajax succes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-dialog, ajax.beginform

i have a modal dialog conataining an `ajax.beginform.`

on a view i have a list of roles for a selected user, when i click `add`, the dialog is created using ajax

view:

```
<div id="popupAgregarRolModal" title="@Res_String.AsaignRol">
    <!-- Client Partial, empty for now -->
</div>


<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".AddRolButton").on("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "Permiso/_GestionarRol?idSelectedUser=" + $("#AdmPerGridBUsquedaUsuarioSelectedRow").val(),
                type: "GET",
            })
            .done(function (result) {
                $("#popupAgregarRolModal").html(result).dialog({ modal: true, height: 'auto', width: 'auto', resizable: false });
            });
        });
    });

    function closeDialogNuevoRol(Result) {
        $("#popupAgregarRolModal").dialog('destroy');
    }

</script>
```

, the dialog contains an ajax.beginform like:

```
 using (Ajax.BeginForm("SetPermiso", "Permiso", new AjaxOptions
            {
                UpdateTargetId = "ABMPermisos",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                OnSuccess = "closeDialogNuevoRol"

            }, new { @id = "AddRolForm" }
                                  )
                   )
            { 
.
.
.
```

the idea is that after i add a new rol to my user, the ajax target upload the list of roles on the view, this is done on my controler by using `redirecttoaction` if all comprobation and insertion logic hapends, then i whant to close the dialg but i only get

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization;
>   attempted to call method 'destroy'

Answer (score 0):

To close a jQuery modal dialog, you can use this:

```
$("#popupAgregarRolModal").dialog("close");
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Try initializing the modal like this and not inside the click event of the button:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#popupAgregarRolModal").dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, resizable: false, draggable: false });
});
```

Then you can have a separate function for the click event.

```
$(".AddRolButton").click(function () {
    //Do stuff
});
```

[This post might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959639/return-partialview-from-jsonresult-actionmethod-back-to-ajax-post-and-display-th/15960456#15960456)

Comment: using destroy or close, i get the same result